# Many-To-Many Association on Same Model using Waterline & Sails.js

Tags: orm, sails.js, models, waterline

I am trying to create a many-to-many relationship on one model in Sail.js using Waterline. The model is as follows and is called "Disciplne" (i.e. academic discipline):

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    'name': {
        type: 'string',
        unique: true,
        required: true,
      lowercase: true
    },
    'users': {
        collection: 'user',
        via: 'discipline'
    },
    recommendations: {
        collection: 'recommendation',
        via: 'discipline'
    },
    related: {
        collection: 'discipline',
        via: 'related'  
    }
  }

};
```

The key attributed here is `related`, with which I am trying to setup a many-to-many relationship that refers to other records in the `Discipline` model. When I run this Sails.js automatically creates a join table called `discipline_related__discipline_related`, which is as it should be I think. Then when I attempt to create a new discipline document with a related id, here is what happens.

First, I try to create the new discipline:

[image: Creating the new discipline with related discipline specified]

The id here pertains to an existing discipline 'political science'. The result, however, as you can see from the image, does not include the `related` field. And if I then query the contents of that model, again the `related` field does not show up:

[image: End result in discipline model]

The join table, however, is populated, but contains only one id reference, so doesn't really set up the many-to-many relationship:

[image: join table result]

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong here? Or does Waterline + Sails.js simply not support this functionality?